# How to change colors in eclipse compare view

Tags: eclipse

I use version Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19.0) and I have trouble seeing the changes in the Eclipse Compare View. I tried changing the colors in the `Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts` and there in `Text Compare`:

[image: Text Compare Colors and Fonts in Preferences]

The deletion color in the setting is (255, 0, 0), thus a powerful red. The resulting colors in the compare viewer however don't look like the setting:

[image: Compare/Patch Preferences]

The result contains a red that is barely visible (255, 204, 204). The color saturation is lower and brightness much higher.

I guess the colors are somehow merged with other color settings. So how I can set or compute the colors that I would like to see?

Comment: It looks like the compare viewer `TextMergeViewer` does this by merging the colour with the list background colour. The merge is hard coded and can't be changed. See `org.eclipse.compare.contentmergeviewer.TextMergeViewer.ColorPalette`

Comment: @greg-449 which background list is merged and how can I change its colour to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: The list the colour is part of - so Working Copy or Baseline in your example image. I don't think there is any way to arrange the colours to give what you want.